# Use import in firebase cloud functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to run firebase cloud functions with `"serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions"` on my local machine which has node version 12.
I cannot use `.mjs` extension because if I use .mjs firebase wont recognize it and gives me this error:

`Error: Cannot find module '/home/rumesh/IdeaProjects/firebaseapp/functions'`

Cannot use `"type":module` in package.json gives me this error:

```
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of /home/rumesh/IdeaProjects/firebaseapp/functions/index.js from /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from /home/rumesh/IdeaProjects/firebaseapp/functions/package.json.
```

***How can I use import statements without using require statements in this scenario?***

Comment: filed an issue for this https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/850 as it's part of the supported runtime